# How does scanf("%[^:]]", word) working in C

Tags: c, scanf

```
scanf("%[^:]]", word)
```

I know the command tries to scan user input until ":" is detected, but I am not sure about what does the last "]" in the front part do.

Comment: It works as [documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). Did you take time to carefully read the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what does the last "]" in the <strike>front</strike> format part do?

Nothing useful.

Usually a lone `"]"` will scan in a matching `]`.  If one is found. it is read from `stdin` and thrown away.  Else scanning stops.

Yet since it follows `"%[^:]"`, which continues scanning in data until a `':'` is encountered<sup>1</sup>, a following `"]"` will not occur.

---

The following makes more sense:

```
// Limit input, scan in non-`:` and then and scan in an excluded ':'.
char word[100];
if (scanf("%99[^:]:", word) == 1) Success();
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Scanning continues until a `':'` is the next character, or end-of-file is signaled or input error occurs.